# Azure Batch Job sequential execution not working

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage-queues, azure-webjobs-triggered

We are using azure web job for batch processing, the job will trigger when there is a message in the storage queue.

We have configured the job to execute the messages one by one.

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.Queues.BatchSize = 1;
config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 1;
```

even though  the job is taking multiple messages from the storage queue and executing parallelly.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> taking multiple messages from the storage queue and executing
>   parallelly

How did you judge take multiple messages and executing in parallel? Did you have multiple instances?

I test the code in different situations.

1)The normal [situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM98X.png) ,not set the `batchsize`, it will drag all messages in the queue.However i think it still run one by one.But from the result i think it won't wait last running completely over.[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHhht.png) is result.

2)Set the `batchsize` to 1, if you debug the code or refresh the queue frequently, you will find it did drag one message one time run. And here is [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IZoh.png).

3) Set the `batchsize` to three and debug , it just change the message number dragged, each time it will drag 3 messages, then it will run like normal without setting `batchsize`.[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxTFZ.png) is the result.And i found if you just run not debug , the [order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HN0J.png) console showing is very orgnized.

So if you don't have other instance running, i think this is working in sequential mode.
If this doesn't match your requirements or you still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: I have a table where it will track the message execution status, pending->inprocess->completed/failed. in this case for all the messages in the Queue status is changing to in process as soon as it arrives in the queue.

Comment: @ Shubham Kalantri in your case , if message execution status is in process, what about its status in queue. It's dragged  or not. And are all message dragged or just one.

Comment: Thank you George Chen for your time. That BatchSize setting works for us. We had some azure environment problem because of that it was not working.

Comment: @ Shubham Kalantri what do you mean? You have found the problem? Di you solve the problem?

Comment: @ George Chen , Yes that problem has been solved. Thank You.